# BizTalk 2013 WCF-WebHttp Adapter and JWT Bearer token

Tags: wcf, rest, biztalk, biztalk-2013, webhttp

We want to expose a WCF Rest Web service in combination with a JWT Bearer token.

In BizTalk 2013 you can use a WCF WebHttp adapter and use ServiceBehavior and EndpointBehavior or use a custom behavior.

I was not able to find documentation on how to use the available behaviors.

How validating a token in BizTalk? The examples I found are with Azure and with fix user with token, but not on-premise BizTalk 2013.

Can someone help me with information about implementing the WCF WebHttp adapter?

Edit: I need a starting point. I have created an rest service and don't know how to change it with an Authorization header with a token.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.